# ASP.NET Google Analytics won't find the script

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

So I put the Google Analytics script into a separate .js file (obviously without the tags should someone ask) and included it on the Master Page but Google keeps telling me `"Tracking not installed"`. The script does show up when running the page inspector.

Here is a link to the code of my Master Page:
http://pastebin.com/mJ8WRWYP

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Dictionary.master.cs" Inherits="Dictionary" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Resources/favicon.ico"/>
    <title>Dictionary</title>
    <script src="Resources/GoogleAnalytics.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="WordCount"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="LoginHPL" NavigateUrl="~/LoginPage.aspx" runat="server">Login</asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="AddWordsHPL" NavigateUrl="~/AddWords.aspx" Visible="false" runat="server">Add Words</asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="ApproveHPL" NavigateUrl="~/ApprovePage.aspx" Visible="false" runat="server">Approve Words</asp:HyperLink>
         <asp:Button ID="LogoutBtn" Visible="false" Style="position: absolute; right: 50px;" runat="server" Text="Logout" OnClick="LogoutBtn_Click" />

    </footer>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd be very grateful for some help.

Comment: sre you sure that the URL resolves in your master page, that you've pasted your tracking code into the appropriate location in your .js, and that the URL for your account matches the domain of the site?

Comment: Well, this shows up in my IIS log file:
2015-02-27 00:55:47 192.168.18.102 GET / - 8000 - 66.249.88.219 Google_Analytics_Snippet_Validator - 200 0 0 554
So it seems Google does access the page.

Also this doesn't work either: http://pastebin.com/wPTGgSKP

Comment: How long has it been since you've installed the tracking code?  It was a few years ago when I initially set mine up, but I seem to recall the site taking a few hours before it started reporting "Receiving Data".

Comment: Around an hour ago but below the status you can also check the last time your website was accessed:
Status: Tracking Not Installed
Last checked: Feb 26, 2015 5:29:30 PM PST

Comment: did you get any solution? maybe using onclient click event